# What is the Tengwar transliteration of this Gandalf quote fom the Lord of the Rings

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, translation

I searched the web for someone to trust to make a transliteration in Tengwar and no one that I have asked has gotten back to me, so here I am.

I want to make a tattoo in Tengwar (preferably the italic/annatar style) with the quote by Gandalf “All we have to decide is what to do with the time that is given to us”.

Comment: [Related, possible duplicate.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/263245/translation-for-a-lotr-tattoo)

Comment: There are many tengwar fonts available free by asking the bingleduck; perhaps if you download one of them, use a graphic program to design your tattoo, and bring it to a reputable tattooist near you, you can get what you want.

Comment: Danger!  Danger, Will Robinson!  Beware of getting a tattoo in a language you can't read at sight; it's frightfully easy to go the rest of your life with the equivalent of Engrish on your skin.  Easy enough even in your native language...

Comment: ^_^ And if you're really unlucky, you wind up with "Translator not available" or "Apply to rear" because the wrong thing got translated.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots  "I am not in the office as I am singing praises to Elbereth"

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Caution, those fonts don't map Latin letters directly to their corresponding Elvish letters. In fact they can't be mapped one to one (about 36 Tengwar with a couple of additional Tehtar),

Comment: @Eugene - I'll be damned if I can find where I got them, but I've had fonts that actually do map correctly for transliteration, including using "ligatures" for glyphs such as _ngoldo_, and making vowels accessible as combining _tehtar_. So, yes, your caution is appropriate, but appropriate fonts _can_ be found, _more..._

Comment: _...more_ and even an improperly-mapped font can be used if you have a specimen sheet for the font and an adequate reference such as [Wikipedia on Tengwar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tengwar), the [Ardalambion](https://folk.uib.no/hnohf/), or the various [Tengwar mappings at Omniglot](https://omniglot.com/conscripts/index.htm#t).

Answer (score 0):

I checked out this: [www.tecendil.com](https://www.tecendil.com/?q=All%20we%20have%20to%20decide%20is%20what%20to%20do%20with%20the%20time%20that%20is%20given%20to%20us&font=TengwarAnnatarItalic) and a quick scan of the text seems to look right:

[image: All we have to decide is what to do with the time that is given to us, written in Tengwar of Fëanor]

This is assuming you want English, using Tengwar script, of course. If so, it's quite easy to fully verify the script just from details widely available, eg the LoTR Apppendix E.

They have a translation into Quenya, though that's courtesy of <*someone on Reddit*>, so obviously caution would be advised.

People cite Tecendil in relation to Tengwar tattoos, and the home page includes the text:

> ...perhaps you're looking for inspiration for your next tattoo

although I doubt they're offering warranties.